# How to increase width of page for the authors' affiliations only?

Tags: margins, revtex, affiliation

I am working with

```
 \documentclass[prl,amsmath,twocolumn,showpacs]{revtex4-1}
```

The line of the authors' affiliations in my paper is too long, and Latex breaks it into two.

I wish to keep it in one line, so how can increase the width of the page effectively (or let one line extend beyond the page margins) to allow for only this line to be longer?

Thanks!

Comment: If this is for publication, don't do it. Use a smaller font if ou have to.  OTOH, \makebox[\textwidth][c]{...} will do what you want.

Comment: @John Kormylo     Ok, great, thanks, but a slightly more detailed explanation would be appreciated: What is [c]? Where do I determine the new, increased, width?

Comment: `\makebox` takes two optional arguments. The first is the width the resulting box will get (but it doesn't resize the contents). The second is the horizontal alignment. `[c]` means centred, so the box will have its contents centred (if bigger than the specified width overlapping equally to both sides). There are also [l] and [r] for left and right aligned, respectively.